# Retain translated position in Android Matrix

Tags: android, matrix

I have translated a view using `onTouchEvent`, And then I have rotated that view with input value like 90 degree. Now I wanted to scale that view without affecting previous translation and rotation, by using following code I retained rotation, but not translation.

```
val scaleValue = 1.2f
val px = rectf.centerX()
val py = rectf.centerY()
matrix.reset()
matrix.setScale(scaleValue, scaleValue, px, py)
matrix.postRotate(rotateAngle, px, py)
```

**Update 1**

```
val scaleFactor = 0.02f
val scaleValue = value * scaleFactor //value is 0...100 
val px = bounds.centerX()
val py = bounds.centerY()
val rectF = RectF()
matrix.mapRect(rectF, bounds)
matrix.reset()
matrix.postTranslate(rectF.centerX(), rectF.centerY())
matrix.postScale(scaleValue, scaleValue, px, py)
matrix.postRotate(rotateAngle, px, py)
```

Comment: so you need, restt() + posttranslate() + postscale() + postrotate()

Comment: @pskink, Yes, But I don't how to find previously translated values. I have tried with `mapRect`, but `posttranslate` translated to somewhere.

Comment: @pskink, I have updated the question

Comment: actually i dont get it: if you rotated the view by 90 degrees so why dont you simply postrotate(90) the existing matrix?

Comment: @pskink, Problem is with translation. Rotate and Scale working as expected. I don't know how to maintain the translated position.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I wanted to scale that view without affecting previous translation and rotation

Then, you should not `reset()` the `matrix`.

```
val scaleValue = 1.2f
val px = rectf.centerX()
val py = rectf.centerY()
//matrix.reset()
matrix.setScale(scaleValue, scaleValue, px, py)
matrix.postRotate(rotateAngle, px, py)
```

If you reset it, all of previous manipulations for the matrix including translations are lost. (As you only show quite few lines of your code, not being reproduce-able, I can't tell *why the rotation is retained though*.)

Comment: `setScale` resets all previous values including `translation`, I want to retain translation also.

Comment: Yup, it's a pretty shitty API imo